# How to make grid not load data when a page is loaded for the first time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to bind my grid to a preloaded data on the first page load so that the grid doesn't make a call to the server again when the page is loaded, but I want the grid to make an ajax call to the server when page changes or filtering is applied.

I've tried putting "autoBind: false", creating "transport" object dynamically right after the grid has been bound to preloaded data, but nothing works or throws an error inside kendo's core.

Here's my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var gridData = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.GridData);

    var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: gridData,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetUsers")',
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                },
                parameterMap: function (options) {
                    return JSON.stringify({ pageSize: options.pageSize, page: options.page });
                }
            },
            ...
            pageSize: gridData.PageSize,
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverPaging: true
        },
        ...
        filterable: true,
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: [10, 25, 50, 100]
        }
    }).data("kendoGrid");
});
```

When I set "data" and "transport" properties on the grid's "datasource" at the same time the "transport" will make a request to a server to get data on the first page load disregarding "data" property which already contains preloaded data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `read` as a function that the first returns your preloaded array. Following calls should invoke `ajax` for loading the data.

```
      // Control if this is the first time it is loaded
      var first = true; 
      // Initial content
      var initial = [
        {
          ProductID: 1000, ProductName: "OnaBai", UnitPrice: 10, Discontinued: false
        }
      ];

      // DataSource definition
      var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        transport: {
          read: function (op) {
            if (first) {
              // If it is first return initial content and toggle first
              op.success(initial);
              first = false;
            } else {
              // Subsequent runs use jquery.ajax for loading the data
              $.ajax({
                url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Products",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function(result) {
                  // Return loaded data
                  op.success(result);
                },
                error : function(result) {
                  op.error(result);
                }  
              }); 
            }
          }
        }
      });

      $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        filterable: true,
        dataSource : dataSource
      });
```

Check it running here: http://dojo.telerik.com/@OnaBai/akoJ

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.data()` function after the DataSource is created to set the data without killing the `transport.read` options.

```
var gridData = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.GridData);

var gridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: '@Url.Action("GetUsers")',
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            },
            parameterMap: function (options) {
                return JSON.stringify({ pageSize: options.pageSize, page: options.page });
            }
        },
        ...
        pageSize: gridData.PageSize,
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverPaging: true
    });

gridDataSource.data(gridData);

var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: gridDataSource,
    ...
    filterable: true,
    pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: [10, 25, 50, 100]
    }
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

Comment: This looks like a nice solution, but I couldn't get it to work since I get an error "undefined is not a function" when trying to execute "gridDataSource.data(gridData);".